replication of data retrieved from db in frontend
I am currently building a simple eccomerce platform using react, express js and mysql as database.
now as i am retrieving data from the database to produce the products it does replicated it self into multiple instances like, product 1 then it will be displayed as 3 products with the same name and ID
this is the code
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const [editedProduct, setEditedProduct] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ProductCard mounted with product:', product);
        return () => {
            console.log('ProductCard unmounted');
        };
    }, [product]);

    if (!product) {
        return <div>Product data is not available</div>;
    }

    const handleEditClick = () => {
        setIsEditing(true);
        setEditedProduct(product); // Pre-fill form with current product data
    };

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setEditedProduct(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    };

    const handleUpdate = async () => {
        try {
            await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/products/${product.product_id}`, editedProduct);
            alert('Product updated successfully');
            setIsEditing(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating product:', error);
            alert('Error updating product');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='procard'>
            <div className='productimg' style={{ width: '100%', height: '65%' }}>
                <img
                    style={{ width: '98%', height: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}
                    src={product.image_url || 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'}
                    alt={product.product_name || 'Product Image'}
                />
            </div>
            <div className='productdesc' style={{ width: '100%', height: '35%' }}>
                {isEditing ? (
                    <div className='product-edit'>
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            name='product_name'
                            value={editedProduct.product_name || ''}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            placeholder='Product Name'
                        />
                        <textarea
                            name='description'
                            value={editedProduct.description || ''}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            placeholder='Description'
                        />
                        <input
                            type='number'
                            name='quantity'
                            value={editedProduct.quantity || ''}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            placeholder='Quantity'
                        />
                        <input
                            type='number'
                            name='size'
                            value={editedProduct.size || ''}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                            placeholder='Size (ml)'
                        />
                        <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update Product</button>
                        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(false)}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className='product-data'>
                        <p>{product.product_name || 'No product name'}</p>
                        <div className='order-options'>
                            <button>Add to Cart</button>
                            <button>Buy Now</button>
                            <button onClick={handleEditClick}>Edit Product</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const ProductList = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ProductList mounted');
        const fetchProducts = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products');
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log('Fetched products:', response.data);
                    
                    const uniqueProducts = Array.from(new Map(response.data.map(product => [product.product_id, product])).values());
                    setProducts(uniqueProducts);
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`Unexpected response status: ${response.status}`);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching products:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
                setError('Error fetching products: ' + (error.response ? error.response.data : error.message));
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchProducts();
        return () => {
            console.log('ProductList unmounted');
        };
    }, []); // Empty dependency array to ensure effect runs only once on mount

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (error) {
        return <div>{error}</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div className='product-list'>
            {products.length > 0 ? (
                products.map(product => (
                    <ProductCard key={product.product_id} product={product} />
                ))
            ) : (
                <div>No products available</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductList;



i did try to console log it so that i could see if the query is working and has no duplication of data so far it does not replicate
however on my fronend this is the issue

this is my backend query

app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [rows] = await db.query('SELECT * FROM product');
        const uniqueProducts = Array.from(new Map(rows.map(product => [product.product_id, product])).values());
        console.log('Fetched unique products:', uniqueProducts);
        res.json(uniqueProducts);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error fetching products');
    }
});



ithink this is the code that triggers mulitple api request
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/products');
            if (response.status === 200) {
              
                const uniqueProducts = Array.from(new Set(response.data.map(p => p.product_id)))
                    .map(id => response.data.find(p => p.product_id === id));
                setProducts(uniqueProducts);
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Unexpected response status: ${response.status}`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setError('Error fetching products: ' + (error.response ? error.response.data : error.message));
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    
    fetchProducts();
}, []); 

i wanted that whenever i display the data from the db there will be no duplication of data

You can try querying the database for unique products using the DISTINCT SQL keyword.

@prasad_ still on the rendering for frontend it does display duplicated data of products but in the console output of the products it does not provide dupliocated –

Hi, How much is product.length at this statement {products.length > 0 ? (...? Is it with respect to the number of records from the DB or greater than that?

@WeDoTheBest4You yes

Hi, Can you please show the JSX statement of this component ProductList ? The code which invokes this.

return (
<div className='product-list' style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
{products.slice(0, 4).map((product) => (

))}

);
@WeDoTheBest4You

Please show the component which has the  JSX code 

What is a unique product? Is it unique by product id or product code or product name?

@prasad_ id of the product

Use set to remove duplicate values.
const products = []
const uniqueProducts = [new Set(...products)]
console.log(uniqueProducts) // No duplicate value


still on the rendering for frontend it does display duplicated data of products but in the console output of the products it does not provide dupliocated

my bad. my frontend put multple 
thus rendering it 4 times

No issues, It happens at times. Glad to know that you have now found it.

thanks for the help ghad i was doing  and debugin from morning till now afternoon

i found it by the network as i see the productcard as the initiator of the api so i look into it and found this quad

Ok bye bye, take care.
